# Game Events run fine, but scene does not render

Tags: java, rendering, game-engine, lwjgl

I am creating my own simple game engine for use in some of my upcoming projects. I have a world Object that stores a bunch of objects that extend a base class RenderObject.

RenderObject contains things like scale rotation position smooth shading or not, etc. and forces all extending classes to implement their own method render().

To navigate my world, I have an FPS style camera control setup, which I've tested via system.out.println() to check pitch and yaw and it's working correctly.

**However none of my objects are rendering.
My world objet has a method called renderObjects() which cycles through all the objects in the world and calls the render() function of them.** *FIXED - New problem...
Now I'm getting 4 2x2 pixel dots that randomly fly around, in a specific place. and then I move my mouse the entire cluster moves. Each game tick the onUpdate() method is called, and then lookThrough()*

FPSCameraControl.java

```
public class FPSCameraControl
{
    private boolean DEBUG = false;

    public Vector3f position = null;
    public float yaw = 0.0f;
    public float pitch = 0.0f;

    public FPSCameraControl(float x, float y, float z)
    {
        position = new Vector3f(x, y, z);
    }
    public void yaw_(float amount)
    {
        yaw -= amount;
        if(yaw>360){
            yaw=0+(yaw-360);
        }
        if(yaw<1){
            yaw=360-(1-yaw);
        }
    }
    public void pitch_(float amount)
    {
        pitch -= amount;
        if(pitch>=155)
        {
            pitch=155;
        }
        if(pitch<=25)
        {
            pitch=25;
        }
    }
    public void walkForward(float distance)
    {
        position.x -= -distance * (float)Math.sin(Math.toRadians(yaw));
        position.z += -distance * (float)Math.cos(Math.toRadians(yaw));
    }
    public void walkBackwards(float distance)
    {
        position.x += -distance * (float)Math.sin(Math.toRadians(yaw));
        position.z -= -distance * (float)Math.cos(Math.toRadians(yaw));
    }
    public void strafeLeft(float distance)
    {
        position.x -= distance * (float)Math.sin(Math.toRadians(yaw-90));
        position.z += distance * (float)Math.cos(Math.toRadians(yaw-90));
    }
    public void strafeRight(float distance)
    {
        position.x -= distance * (float)Math.sin(Math.toRadians(yaw+90));
        position.z += distance * (float)Math.cos(Math.toRadians(yaw+90));
    }
    public void lookThrough()
    {
        GL11.glRotatef(pitch, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        GL11.glRotatef(yaw, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        GL11.glTranslatef(position.x, position.y, position.z);
    }
    public void onUpdate()
    {
        debug("Updating View");

        //Calculate Sensitivity

        float sen = (0.02F*10);

        debug("Sensitivity: " + sen);

        //Get Center Of Screen

        int cx = Display.getDisplayMode().getWidth()/2;
        int cy = Display.getDisplayMode().getHeight()/2;

        //Get Mouse Position From Center

        int x = Mouse.getX()-cx;
        int y = Mouse.getY()-cy;

        debug("Mouse Moved: " + x + ", " + y);

        //Apply Inverting If Set



        //Apply Sensitivity

        float _yaw = (x*sen);
        float _pitch = (y*sen);

        yaw_(_yaw);
        pitch_(_pitch);

        debug("New Yaw: " + yaw);
        debug("New Pitch: " + pitch);

        UpdatePosition();

        //SET MOUSE TO CENTER

        Mouse.setCursorPosition(cx, cy);

        lookThrough();
    }
    public void printROT()
    {
        System.out.println("Pitch : "+pitch);
        System.out.println("Yaw : "+yaw);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("XYZ : "+position.x+", "+position.y+", "+position.z);
    }

    public void debug(String msg)
    {
        if(DEBUG)
        {
            System.out.println(msg);
        }
    }

    public void UpdatePosition()
    {
        float f=0;
        float b=0;
        float r=0;
        float l=0;
        boolean moved =false;
        boolean shift = Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_LSHIFT);
        if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_W))
        {
            if(shift)
            {
                f=0.04F;
            }
            else
            {
                f=0.02F;
            }
            moved=true;
        }
        if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_S))
        {
            if(shift)
            {
                b=0.04F;
            }
            else
            {
                b=0.02F;
            }
            moved=true;
        }
        if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_D))
        {
            if(shift)
            {
                r=0.025F;
            }
            else
            {
                r=0.016F;
            }
            moved=true;
        }
        if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_A))
        {
            if(shift)
            {
                l=0.02F;
            }
            else
            {
                l=0.016F;
            }
            moved=true;
        }
        if(moved)
        {
            walkForward(f);
            walkBackwards(b);
            strafeLeft(l);
            strafeRight(r);
        }
    }
}
```

RenderObject.java

```
public abstract class RenderObject
{
    public  double []  location  =  new  double [] {0, 0, 0};
    public  double []  rotation  =  new  double [] {0, 0, 0};
    public  double []     scale  =  new  double [] {1, 1, 1};
    public Color color = new Color(180, 180, 180);

    public boolean smooth = false;

    public RenderObject parent = null;
    public LinkedList<RenderObject> children = new LinkedList<RenderObject>();

    public abstract void render();

    public void setScale(double x, double y, double z)
    {
        scale = new double[]{x, y, z};
    }

    public void setParent(RenderObject object)
    {
        parent = object;
    }
    public void removeParent()
    {
        parent = null;
    }
    public RenderObject getParent()
    {
        return parent;
    }
    public void addChild(RenderObject object)
    {
        object.setParent(this);
        children.add(object);
    }
    public void removeChild(RenderObject object)
    {
        if(children.contains(object))
        {
            object.removeParent();
            children.remove(object);
        }
    }
}
```

And RenderCube.java

```
public class RenderCube extends RenderObject
{
    @Override
    public void render()
    {
        if(smooth)
        {
            GL11.glShadeModel(GL11.GL_SMOOTH);
        }
        else
        {
            GL11.glShadeModel(GL11.GL_FLAT);
        }
        GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);

        GL11.glPushMatrix();

        GL11.glColor3b( color.getRedByte(),color.getGreenByte(), color.getBlueByte() );

        GL11.glRotated(rotation[0], 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        GL11.glRotated(rotation[1], 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
        GL11.glRotated(rotation[2], 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

        //TOP
        GL11.glNormal3d(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
        GL11.glVertex3d(location[0]-scale[0], location[1]+scale[1], location[2]-scale[2]);
        GL11.glVertex3d(location[0]-scale[0], location[1]+scale[1], location[2]+scale[2]);
        GL11.glVertex3d(location[0]+scale[0], location[1]+scale[1], location[2]+scale[2]);
        GL11.glVertex3d(location[0]+scale[0], location[1]+scale[1], location[2]-scale[2]);

        //BOTTOM
        GL11.glNormal3d(0.0, -1.0, 0.0);
        GL11.glVertex3d(location[0]-scale[0], location[1]-scale[1], location[2]-scale[2]);
        GL11.glVertex3d(location[0]-scale[0], location[1]-scale[1], location[2]+scale[2]);
        GL11.glVertex3d(location[0]+scale[0], location[1]-scale[1], location[2]+scale[2]);
        GL11.glVertex3d(location[0]+scale[0], location[1]-scale[1], location[2]-scale[2]);

        //FRONT
        GL11.glNormal3d(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        GL11.glVertex3d(location[0]-scale[0], location[1]+scale[1], location[2]+scale[2]);
        GL11.glVertex3d(location[0]+scale[0], location[1]+scale[1], location[2]+scale[2]);
        GL11.glVertex3d(location[0]+scale[0], location[1]-scale[1], location[2]+scale[2]);
        GL11.glVertex3d(location[0]-scale[0], location[1]-scale[1], location[2]+scale[2]);

        //BACK
        GL11.glNormal3d(0.0, 0.0, -1.0);
        GL11.glVertex3d(location[0]-scale[0], location[1]+scale[1], location[2]-scale[2]);
        GL11.glVertex3d(location[0]+scale[0], location[1]+scale[1], location[2]-scale[2]);
        GL11.glVertex3d(location[0]+scale[0], location[1]-scale[1], location[2]-scale[2]);
        GL11.glVertex3d(location[0]-scale[0], location[1]-scale[1], location[2]-scale[2]);

        //RIGHT
        GL11.glNormal3d(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        GL11.glVertex3d(location[0]+scale[0], location[1]+scale[1], location[2]+scale[2]);
        GL11.glVertex3d(location[0]+scale[0], location[1]+scale[1], location[2]-scale[2]);
        GL11.glVertex3d(location[0]+scale[0], location[1]-scale[1], location[2]-scale[2]);
        GL11.glVertex3d(location[0]+scale[0], location[1]-scale[1], location[2]+scale[2]);

        //LEFT
        GL11.glNormal3d(-1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        GL11.glVertex3d(location[0]-scale[0], location[1]+scale[1], location[2]+scale[2]);
        GL11.glVertex3d(location[0]-scale[0], location[1]+scale[1], location[2]-scale[2]);
        GL11.glVertex3d(location[0]-scale[0], location[1]-scale[1], location[2]-scale[2]);
        GL11.glVertex3d(location[0]-scale[0], location[1]-scale[1], location[2]+scale[2]);

        Color _color = new Color(180, 180, 180);

        GL11.glColor3b( _color.getRedByte(),_color.getGreenByte(), _color.getBlueByte() );

        GL11.glPopMatrix();

        GL11.glEnd();
    }
}
```

Does anyone see what might not be working? Cause I don't.

Comment: I'm really not a pro in java 3d graphics but I never see you swapping the front and back buffers.

Comment: in my main loop I am calling Display.update() if that's what you are refering to.

Comment: Try looking at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8950138/java-lwjgl-when-i-call-gl11-glend-the-polygon-disappears, maybe it can help.

Comment: ok, now I'm getting random dots flying around everywhere...

Comment: Do you call glLoadIdentity before you start drawing a new frame, because right now it seems like you're carrying your transforms from frame to frame.

Comment: On the page I was just linked to, it said to put that before the game loop, it never said anything about putting it in every frame. I'll try that. Do I put it before or after `GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);`

Comment: I believe so, again, I'm no pro.  The purpose is to get a "clean slate" every time you start rendering again to avoid starting your rotations/translations from the last position you were at the end of drawing your last frame.

Comment: Ok, no more randomly moving dots, but still have dots, just they don't move unles I move the mouse.

Comment: At this point, I'm not sure I can help you further.  I would try removing the calls to glNormal3d and see what happens.  Also, maybe the dots you're seeing are actually your quads but they're too small/far and you see them as dots so you could try playing with translation/scale parameters.

Comment: that's the thing, I belive that is the thing, however no matter how I do anything with my FPS, I can never get the camera to move towards the objects. even though the objects should be only 3 units away from the camera and be 2x2x2 units large..

Comment: I don't think your camera class is 100% correct, because you're basically applying your rotations twice.  When you rotate in OpenGL, you rotate the entire coordinate system, then subsequent transformations are applied on top of that.  Knowing this, you don't want to take rotation into account in your walkTowards/etc methods, you only want to increment/decrement distance by a fixed value.  Also, try to see if GL11 exposes a gluLookAt function: http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual/gluLookAt.3G.html.  It makes cameras so much easier.

Comment: I've used this camera before. I have a property that stores the rotation of the camera, and I use that for movement, not eh global rotation. the camera rotates the entire coordinate system, and then any rotation done before rendering an object then defines the rotation of that object. Even disableing the second rotation. I have had large planes with objects on them, some rotated and such, and this camera navigated the world just as I wanted it to. there's no reason the camera should not work in this situation. And the gluLookAt would require a lot of changing...

Comment: Then I have reached the limits of what I can do without setting up an entire java development stack on my work computer :P  Good luck to you, I hope you come back to explain when you figure it out!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11836/discussion-between-d3-jmultiply-and-pwny)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing was rendering at all.

When I added:

```
GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
GL11.glLoadIdentity();
GL11.glOrtho(-500, 500, -281, 281, -1, 1);
GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
```

It started rendering, I did not think about the fact that at this point I was rendining in Orthographic view. I replaced that with:

```
GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
GL11.glLoadIdentity();      
GLU.gluPerspective(45.0f, ((float) 800) / ((float) 600), 0.1f, 100.0f);
GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
GL11.glHint(GL11.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL11.GL_NICEST);
```

And the scene rendered completely. However my camera is stilla  little messy, but this proves that my engine is working correctly so far now. the camera isn't part of the engine, it's something I made for the test, so the "Engine" is working correctly.

To make things simple, I'm going to have the World contain a Camera object, which will control the viewing location, angle, FoV, etc.

Thanks for the help @pwny - you did help, just a simple change.